# What would be a convenient way to count the number of HTTP requests made by a block of code?

Tags: ruby, http

Suppose I want to be able to write a test like this:

```
lambda {
  do_something_involving_web_requests
}.should make(1).http_requests
```

It seems to me there would be several possible ways to implement this kind of functionality; however, it *also* seems that:

1. Someone might have already done so (in which case I want to look into their solution); or
2. Someone on StackOverflow might have an idea I haven't thought of.

So, has this been done already? And/or what are your ideas?

Comment: This question is a bit vague. What's your testing framework? rspec?

Comment: You could redefine the method in Net:HTTP, with an variable to catch each call instead of making the call, then check the value of that variable matches the correct one in match? Not seen anyone do that before though.

Comment: @MarkThomas: I suppose you're right that it's vague; but my intention isn't to find a solution given a specific testing framework. It's more to fish for ideas such as what Joe suggested: monkeypatch Net::HTTP, for example. Shouldn't testing framework (you're right--RSpec in this case) not really matter?

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in more granular testing of how your app responds to specific HTTP responses, rather than simply counting requests, you can use mocks. Here's how to use RSpec's mocks to test http requests:

```
@mock_http = mock("http")
Net::HTTP.stub!(:start).and_yield @mock_http
@mock_http.should_receive(:get).with("/")
```

One library I use is [Fakeweb](http://fakeweb.rubyforge.org/). Fakeweb does what @Joe mentions: it hooks into Net::HTTP and can be configured to return a canned response from a given URL. Many other HTTP libs depend on Net::HTTP so this technique has broad compatibility. Fakeweb example from its docs:

```
  FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, "http://example.com/test1", :body => "Hello World!")

  Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://example.com/test1"))
  => "Hello World!"
```

Neither of these methods have a simple access count though, if you want that you can use [rspec-mocks](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames) which has the following method count functionality (these can be used on stubs or test doubles):

```
double.should_receive(:msg).once
double.should_receive(:msg).twice
double.should_receive(:msg).exactly(n).times
double.should_receive(:msg).at_least(:once)
double.should_receive(:msg).at_least(:twice)
double.should_receive(:msg).at_least(n).times
double.should_receive(:msg).at_most(:once)
double.should_receive(:msg).at_most(:twice)
double.should_receive(:msg).at_most(n).times
double.should_receive(:msg).any_number_of_times
```